# Test AWS s3 PUT and Download in Pytest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, moto

I have the following function.

```
def test_download(test_args):
    mock = mock_s3()
    mock.start()
    conn = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
    conn.create_bucket(Bucket=test_args.source_bucket)
    s3.Object(test_args.source_bucket, 'testing.txt').put(
        Body=open("testing.txt", 'rb'))
    handler_client = HandlerClient(test_args)
    handler_client.get_s3_file()
```

Using `from moto import mock_s3`

I get the error when I go to test.

```
    def add_auth(self, request):
        if self.credentials is None:
>           raise NoCredentialsError
E           botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials at line
>       `conn.create_bucket(Bucket=test_args.source_bucket)`
```

I have tried with the decorator
as well as

```
with moto.mock_s3():
```

All get the same error. How can I resolve making this issue to create a fake bucket drop an item in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`moto` unfortunately does not mock the authorization parts of `boto3`. So you need to have some part of the AWS Authorization Chain set up, e.g. exporting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. We usually set up a fixture to update the environment before each test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def context():
    context = attrdict.AttrMap()
    orig_env = os.environ.copy()
    os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'foo'
    os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'bar'
    context.os = {'environ': os.environ}
    yield context
    os.environ = orig_env
```

The import part is setting the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, then `yield`ing, then restoring the `os.environ` back to its original state. You don't have to use the `context = attrdict.AttrMap` part, we like that so test functions using this fixture have access to the test `os.environ` (and other test) attributes.

Comment: This is generally useful in any tests. Putting bogus credentials will catch cases where you forget to mock out the service or otherwise prevent a live request.

Comment: Great point @JordonPhillips! We have definitely seen tests modify real AWS resources. I swear this happened once even with the correct `moto` mocks.